# Speeding up pandas profiling analysis using check_correlation?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

Using pandas profiling to generate a report. the size of the dataset is very large to speed up the processing im trying to turn off correlations so i used check_correlations from another post I saw,
ValueError: Config parameter "check_correlation" does not exist. is then the issue I get from using this line

```
a = prof.ProfileReport(df, title='Downloads', check_correlation=False)
```

which generates this issue of

ValueError: Config parameter "check_correlation" does not exist.

Comment: prof = pandas_profiling ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they have changed the configurations on version 2, you could use it as:

```
import pandas_profiling

profile = df.profile_report(check_correlation_pearson=False,
correlations={'pearson': False,
'spearman': False,
'kendall': False,
'phi_k': False,
'cramers': False,
'recoded': False})
```

to turn off correlations. However, it is still not as fast as version 1.4. You could also investigate other configurations [here](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/master/pandas_profiling/config_default.yaml).

Answer (score 4):

This way didn't work for me and I used:

a = prof.ProfileReport(df, title='Downloads', minimal=True)

Answer (score 0):

Please, see this
[issue](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/62) in pandas-profiling project.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.6+ you can do this:

```
profile = df.profile_report(
    title="Report without correlations",
    correlations={
        "auto": {"calculate": False},
        "pearson": {"calculate": False},
        "spearman": {"calculate": False},
        "kendall": {"calculate": False},
        "phi_k": {"calculate": False},
        "cramers": {"calculate": False},
    },
)

# or using a shorthand that is available for correlations
profile = df.profile_report(
    title="Report without correlations",
    correlations=None,
)
```

See also [the docs here](https://pandas-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/advanced_usage/available_settings.html#correlations).